# Asking for permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I found that handling authorizations from android M and up is missing something. Or at the very least google had other ideas about this then i have.
In my reasoning for authorizations there are 4 options:

1 app has permission
2 app does not have permission

2a never asked the user

2b user has denied

2c user has denied + checked "do not ask again"-box.

Checking between 1 and 2 is easy. But then is starts because there is just 1 method available to check between 2a, 2b and 2c. So....how as this method returns a Boolean?
With the method you can check for a 2b scenario but you do not know (in case of result = true) if it is a 2a or 2c.

What is an option is that google expects us to keep asking the user over and over even is the user checked the "do not ask again"-box.
That seems ok is you need the rights for core options of your app. In my case however the rights are needed for an extra.

The only option i found so far is saving data in the app data so i can check for the 4 different states. Does anybody have a smarter idea.

Comment: _"google expects us to keep asking the user over and over even is the user checked the "do not ask again"-box"_ `requestPermissions` will not trigger a dialog if the user has selected "do not ask again" previously.

Comment: Michael thanks for the very fast response. I understand your answer but it is not complety helping met. Let me try to make it more clear. Accoording to the documentation it says this: method, shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(), that returns true if the user has previously denied the request, and returns false if a user has denied a permission and selected the Don't ask again option in the permission request dialog, or if a device policy prohibits the permission. So like i sayed: false is 2c but true is 2a or 2b so when should i show more info?

Comment: If 2a is the first time your app ever asks the user for the permission, then actually it's `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` true -> 2b, false -> 2a or 2c. And as for _"when should i show more info?"_: when `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns true.

Comment: Yes, you are right. "True -> 2b, False -> 2a or 2c" but the problem remains. What to do when shouldShowRequestPermissionRetionale returns false? How do i know if i should perform the actions of 2a (only als permission) or perform an action to disable the selected option because the user really does not want to give the permission (2c)?

Comment: I don't see how there is a problem. If `checkSelfPermission` says that you currently don't have the permission, then you first call `shouldShowPermissionRationale`. If it returns true you can show a rationale dialog if you want to, otherwise you don't. After that you call `requestPermissions`, which may or may not trigger a system dialog. When you get the `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback you either call the function(s) that require the permission (if it was granted), or you don't (if it wasn't granted).

Comment: Michael thank you very much. with your heplp and some testing i have found where my reasoning went wrong. Now have it working :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael i found where i went wrong.
My error wat in the fact that Android (Google) does not show the requestPermission dialog when the user has checked the "do not ask again"-box even when you program it.
My next error was then how do i get an "false" back knowing that there is no permission
but android does execute the onRequestPermissionsResult method even if the dialog has not been shown.

Again: Thanks Michael

Comment: what I have done in previous applications is check at the start of each Activity that the appropriate permissions are granted (i.e. Gather a boolean value seeing if the permissions are allowed, not specifically worry about the dialog shown to the user because you can't always control that if they opt not to see the notification). If permissions are not granted, load a restricted version of your Activity stating permissions are required (Uber does something very similar checking if GPS is enabled before you can request a ride). If permissions are granted show your normal Activity.